# ag Silver Searcher: rules for lookahead/lookbehind patterns?

Tags: regex, vim, vimgrep

I'm using `ag` in Vim with good results for string/file search.

However, there seems to be not much documentation how patterns are constructed for ag.

I'm trying to use ag instead of vimgrep in an example from the Practical Vim book.

I want to find every occurrence of "Pragmatic Vim" in all files in a directory recursively, and substitute this string with "Practical Vim". There is also "Pragmatic Bookshelf" in some files, and that string must remain.

the book suggests this approach:

```
/Pragmatic\ze Vim
:vimgrep /<C-r>// **/*.txt
```

And after that step, populate quickfix list with `:Qargs` plugin command, and, finally `:argdo %s//Practical/g`

Now, how do I specify `/Pragmatic\ze`pattern using `ag`?

Is `ag` at all designed for what I'm trying to do here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Silver Searcher tool uses PCRE (Perl-Compatible Regular Expression) syntax. So instead of Vim's `\ze`, you need to use the Perl syntax for *positive lookahead*: `(?=pattern)`. (The corresponding *lookbehind* for `\zs` would be `(?<=pattern)`.)

I'm showing your example on the command-line, but it should be identical from within Vim:

```
$ ag 'Pragmatic(?= Vim)'
```

Comment: Thank you. Using `$ ag '(?<=Pragmatic )Vim'` in a directory finds **Vim**, I am trying to find the **Pragmatic** part. However, since I'm trying to populate quickfix with relevant files, this command seems to limit the list to the needed files. I suppose I will need to read up on PCRE. It seems, that I will still need to use `/Practical\ze` for `:argdo %s//Pragmatic/ge` part?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I confused that. It's now corrected. Thanks for accepting my answer!

Comment: You're correct that the PCRE syntax only applies to the external `ag` command. For `:s` inside Vim, you still have to use `\ze`.